# How to resolve 'curl: option --data-raw: is unknown' error

Tags: shell, curl, sh

I am trying to run shell script with a curl command as below with --data-raw as body.

```
curl --location --request POST '<URL>' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw '{
"blocks": [
  {
 "type": "header",
 "text": {
  "type": "plain_text",
  "text": "Help Text",
  "emoji": true
 }
},
{
 "type": "divider"
},
]
}'
```

Output:

```
curl: option --data-raw: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

I couldn't find any error with the json validator. Please suggest a solution. TIA.

Comment: Can you try running the command by pasting the JSON without line breaks?

Comment: Also it looks like your JSON payload is invalid. There is an unexpected `,` after the `"type": "divider"` object

Comment: removing `,` after `"type"` section didnt resolve the issue. But replacing `--data-raw` with just `--data` worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

##### Here, you have 2 issue.

- your JSON is invalid, the `,` line 14 need to be removed
- use `--data` and a *heredoc* :

```
curl --location --request POST '<URL>' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data "@/dev/stdin"<<EOF
{
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "header",
      "text": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Help Text",
        "emoji": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "divider"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```

##### Here documents:

> `cat <<EOF` followed by several lines of text, followed by the literal string `EOF` on a new line, NOT indented. The portion between the `EOF`s is passed to the command as standard input. If `'EOF'` is 'quoted', substitutions WON'T be done; otherwise they are. See `<<-` for the indented variety (not recommended, need TABs).

Comment: Replacing `--data-raw` with `--data` resolved the issue. I tried to use `<<EOF` but it was throwing `invalid_payloadcurl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:
{
 ^`

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem the reason for error was corrected by

**Removing backslash** `\`

**Replacing** `--data-raw` to `--data`

**Keeping header and other keys till starting of json** in single line

instead of following

```
curl --location 'https://reqres.in/api/users' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw
```

to

```
curl --location 'https://reqres.in/api/users' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ 
"json":"body" 
}'
```

I took following from postman throws error as following

**curl: option --data-raw: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information'**

```
curl --location 'https://reqres.in/api/users' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "morpheus",
    "job": "leader",
    "code": {
        "page": 1,
        "per_page": 6,
        "total": 12,
        "total_pages": 2,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in",
                "first_name": "George",
                "last_name": "Bluth",
                "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "support": {
            "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
            "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
        }
    }
}'
```

same data is **corrected** now and is working fine

```
curl --location 'https://reqres.in/api/users' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{
    "name": "morpheus",
    "job": "leader",
    "code": {
        "page": 1,
        "per_page": 6,
        "total": 12,
        "total_pages": 2,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in",
                "first_name": "George",
                "last_name": "Bluth",
                "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "support": {
            "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
            "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
        }
    }
}'
```